# TortoiseGit Repository Browser Icons

Tags: tortoisegit

In the TortoiseGit Repository Browser, there are folder and file icons (with appropriate filetype or associated app styling).

Some file icons in the Repo-Browser have *what appear to be* EXE attached to the icon image.

What is the significance of this extra styling?

Comment: Help 2.6.1 **is not** relevant to the Repo-Browser iconography. (It **is** relevant to the Windows Explorer iconography.) On the other hand, if the iconography shown here is incorrect, then it would be really interesting to learn where it is coming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "EXE" icon overlay indicates that this file is flagged as "executable" in the Git repository (on Windows this flag doesn't have relevance for Git).

The overlay is displayed so that developers (maybe who cloned a repository which is also used on *nix systems) can see on what files the executable flag is set, because this flag is invisible on Windows otherwise (it's only displayed in the file properties on the Git tab for single files).

See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index

Comment: So, in Windows, its presence is a random artifact? This would only have meaning when using TortoiseGit on an operating system other than Windows? I see the EXE overlay has been applied to any number of different files .php, .css, .jpg, .xml, and not always. (There are no executables in this repo.)

Comment: Normally if the core.filemode setting is set to false (the default on Windows), no eecutable should be set automatically or randomly. I haven't tested what happens on WIndows if this setting is not set to false.

Comment: The above link did not lead directly to an on-point answer. The "Configuration" section referenced `core.filemode` in _git-config_ (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-corefileMode). I found the git-config in my repo's .git folder and `core.filemode` is set to false. So, I will conclude my observations (the EXE overlay) are the result of a bug - both in its actuation and in its lack of documentation. Thank you @MrTux.